# Is it possible for an old HDD to be the cause of "repo sync" failure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, git, android

**My setup**:

> - Model: Aspire E5-571G (Aspire E5-571G_0867_V1.32)
> - GPU: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
> - CPU: EA50_HB V1.32
> - RAM: 8 GB
> - OS: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS Trusty

**Target**:

> - Device - Nexus 5x
> - Version - Oreo
> - Tag - android-8.1.0_r52
> - Build - OPM7.181205.001
> - Configuration - user

**Steps taken in order**:

1. Installing dependencies

> - sudo apt install bc bison build-essential ccache curl flex    g++-multilib gcc-multilib git gnupg gperf imagemagick
>     lib32ncurses5-dev lib32readline-dev lib32z1-dev liblz4-tool
>     libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libssl-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libxml2
>     libxml2-utils lzop pngcrush rsync schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc
>     zip zlib1g-dev
> - sudo apt install cmake zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk-headless

2. Setup a bin path in home directory

> mkdir -p ~/bin

3. Install the repo command:

> - curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo >    ~/bin/repo
> - chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

4. Verify the repo binary's checksum.

> sha256sum ~/bin/repo

5. Git identity

> - git config --global user.email ""
> - git config --global user.name ""

6. brotli package

   > - git clone https://github.com/google/brotli.git
   > - cd ~/brotli
   > - ./configure-cmake
   > - make -j(4)
   > - cp brotli ~/bin/
7. Getting the vendor blobs

   > - git clone https://github.com/anestisb/android-prepare-vendor.git
   > - cd android-prepare-vendor
   > - mkdir bullhead-blobs
   > - sudo ./execute-all.sh -k -d bullhead -a bullhead -b OPM7.181205.001 -o bullhead-blobs
8. Downloading AOSP sources

   > - mkdir -p ~/aosp
   > - cd ~/aosp
   > - repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.1.0_r52
   > - repo sync

**Problem description**:

> The list ends here because that is the farthest I was able to reach,
>   first, at home with my at the very best 8 Mbps it takes around 24-60
>   hours to finish repo sync with errors. At first I didn't record logs
>   being completely sure it is okay for repo sync to be run a few dozen
>   times at slow speed that is constantly overloaded in order to finish.
>   But after maybe 5-6 attempts it was clear that it is not the case. The
>   most frequent errors were "linux input/output" "can't fetch" and "end
>   hung up unexpectedly which may not be absolutely correct as those are
>   from my memory. Then I decided to try "repo sync -f" a few times and
>   it ended up the same. That is when I assumed it is a problem of slow
>   connection and interruptions so I took my ethernet cable and went to
>   my friend who has 570 Mbps to see if that helps. Basically, after a
>   few more "repo sync"s and "repo sync -f"s I ended up pretty much the
>   same. Then I tried rm -rf for the "corrupt" paths that I saw in logs
>   to sync them again but to no result. At last I decided to log
>   everything and assume it may be my faulty HDD which is marked as
>   "Likely to fail soon" in "disks", attaching all the log-files below.

Thanks for your replies in advance, I am really dedicated to finish what I have started.
[output](https://pastebin.com/4RQBcBh8)
[output-terminal](https://pastebin.com/XeSx3jir)
[Hardware(lspci)](https://pastebin.com/36CiqpVw)
[HDD_short_test_smartctl](https://pastebin.com/PDshvgkB)

Comment: "Input/output error" in logs on Linux generally indicates a disk failure or disk connection error (e.g. USB drive being suddenly unplugged), if the device is a physical hard drive.

Comment: Also, SMART test showing "Failed" is really bad.  Your hard drive is dying.  Backup data now and replace.

Comment: Thanks, I think my next move will be to try to swap HDD!